# Javascript library to visualize network graph with custom image background

Tags: d3.js, graph, vis.js, topology, ngx-graph

Is there any javascript library for graph (network topology) visualization with support custom image as background with zoom support? Idea is to use floor plan (jpg/png) and change positions of nodes according their real position. I can't find any example with background image. Thank you!

[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2wYp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think this meets your requirement in having a background image to the whole diagram:
https://gojs.net/latest/samples/kittenMonitor.html
Control-mouse-wheel or pinch-zoom to change the scale interactively.

This sample does not happen to show any links connecting the nodes, and those nodes happen to be moving slowly, but those features are not necessary for showing any background image. FYI, I am a developer of GoJS.